# Unusually large cluster size hierarchical clustering in Python

Tags: python-3.x, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying hierarchical clustering in Python with Euclidean distances. One of the clusters comprises of almost 80% data. How do I deal with it?

Comment: Hi! this is not a coding question, maybe you should try a different site for this topic

Answer (score 0):

Are your data are prone to outliers? This might mean that the other datapoints that make up 20% are outliers and that come from faulty measurements or something like this.... or at least that these data are highly removed from the other 80%...

Take the cluster that contains 80% and the others that make up the remaining 20% and explore their data separately.